# unbounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define the sequence $(x_n)$ by $x_1 = 1$, $x_{n+1} = x_n + \sqrt{x_n}$,    for $n \in\Bbb N$.
Prove that $(x_n)$ is unbounded.

Let $\alpha = \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac {x_n}{n^2}$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, prove that there exists $n_\epsilon \in \Bbb N$ such that if $N>n_\epsilon$ then for any $k \in \Bbb N$
$$x_{N+k}-x_n\geq[\frac {(N+k-1)(N+k)}2-\frac {(N-1)(N)}2]\sqrt{\alpha - \epsilon}$$

Comment: Suppose $x_n$ is bounded. Since it is increasing, it is convergent, with limit say, $L$. So, $L = L + \sqrt{L}$, hence, $x_1 = 1 < 0 = L$.

Comment: The interesting part: assuming that $L=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{x_n}{n^2}$ exists, by the Stoltz-Cesaro theorem we get $L=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{L}$, hence $L=\frac{1}{4}$. The next part is just to prove that $x_n$ is bounded between $\frac{1}{4}(n-A)^2$ and $\frac{1}{4}(n+B)^2$; for instance, by induction.

Answer (score 0):

By induction it is easy to see that

$$ x_n \ge n$$

for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

FRED

Answer (score 0):

See that

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\sqrt{x_n}$$

And that

$$x_2>1$$

It then follows that

$$x_3-x_2=\sqrt{x_2}>1$$

And by induction:

$$x_{n+1}-x_n>1$$

Thus, we have

$$x_n>n$$

And since $\liminf_{n\to\infty}n$ is unbounded, so is $x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

We may easily prove by induction that $\color{green}{x_n\leq \frac{1}{4}\left(n+1\right)^2 }$. The claim is fulfilled by $n=1$.
Assuming it holds for some $n$, we get
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n+\sqrt{x_n} \leq \frac{n^2}{4}+n+\frac{3}{4} \leq \frac{1}{4}(n+2)^2$$
hence the claim holds for $(n+1)$, too. In a similar way, we may show that $\color{green}{x_n\geq \frac{1}{4}(n+1)^2-\frac{1}{4}(n-1)}$ holds, too. It follows that
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{x_n}{n^2}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}$$
and the green inequalities can be used to easily prove the second part of your question, too.